# How to import users from a domain controller in moss 2007

Tags: 2007

I have a SharePoint farm in moss 2007 and it is connected to ex1.com domain and i have configured SSP to import users from this domain.
After that i created a new domain ex2.com and i want to configure SSP such that it should import users from this domain controller also.
I tried to create a new connection with this newly created domain(ex2.com) but is giving error "*The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. Please re-enter the domain name or explicitly specify the domain controller and search base*"

Comment: This post may be helpful : http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/adawson/archive/2011/07/06/sharepoint-2007-with-multiple-domains.aspx

Comment: I resolved the issue.The issue was that i was typing domain name instead of domain controller name  in Domain Controller section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.The issue was that i was typing domain name instead of domain controller name in Domain Controller name section.
In domain controller name section, we should enter domain name with the machine name.i.e.
if domain domain is ex2.com and the machine name of the domain is mch1,then we should enter mch1.ex2.com